# vb.net how to reinitialize the base class from derived class after passing some parameters to it

Tags: vb.net

I dont know if is posible, but I need to get recalculated properties of base class after passing parameter to it. Here is an example code:

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Public Property Initial As Integer
    Public Property Coeficient As Integer
    Public Property Multiplier As Integer = Coeficient * Initial

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(0, 1) ' default initialization
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value1 As Integer, ByVal Value2 As Integer)
        Me.Initial = Value1
        Me.Coeficient = Value2
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value As Integer)
        MyBase.New(Value, 3) 'sets the coeficient to 3 and the Initial whatever is passed to it
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TestClas

    Public Sub TestDerivedClass()

        Dim d As New DerivedClass(5)
        Dim result As Integer = d.Multiplier

        MsgBox(result) ' should be 15, but is not, because Multiplier need to be re-initialized somehow

    End Sub

End Class
```

I understand where the problem is, but what I need is to obtain kind of a dynamic base class to be inherited differently in multiple derived classes after passing different parameters to it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That wont assign a formula to `Multiplier` just the value.  Update the value at the same time you update the 2 other properties.

Comment: Ok, but I just give an example, it's not just one case, I have a lot of otther properties to update in the same time, sounds like re-writing the class in different shapes for every situation encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplier is a property, so it's such a Field of your class. When initialize, value is given.

You are expecting a "function behavior".

You can do many things, I don't know what you really need. Change Multiplier :

- from property, to a Function As Integer
- or to a Readonly property
- or write the Get and Set Areas.

Simple Example:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Multiplier As Integer
  Get
    Return Coeficient * Initial
  End Get
End Property
```

This will give you the "automatic behavior" you are expecting

Comment: Thank you, saved my day!

Comment: Pedantic note, fields and properties are not the same thing.  The issue isn't that `Multiplier` is a field (it isn't, it's a property---which is important from the point of view of binary compatibility), the issue is that it's currently implemented as if it were a field.

Answer (score 2):

The value of your `Multiplier` property doesn't get updated. If you want it to always return the multiplication of the other two values, you should convert it to a read-only property which will return the product.

Replace the following line:

```
Public Property Multiplier As Integer = Coeficient * Initial
```

with:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Multiplier() As Integer
    Get
        Return Coeficient * Initial
    End Get
End Property
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's totally fine, we're all here to help. He wasn't actually faster though haha ;) Glad you had your problem solved after all :)

Comment: np, appreciated for help :)